# Node.js electron-prebuilt error cannot find module 'browser-window' windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

right now i'm trying to learn how to program a desktop app using electron but I'm getting this error when trying to run 'npm start' using electron-prebuilt with nodejs x32 on windows 10 x64:

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module 'browser-window'
   at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:438:15)
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\player\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:386:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\player\index.js:4:25)
   at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
```

This is my code:

package.json

```
  {
 "name": "player",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
  "electron-prebuilt": "^1.2.7"
  }
 }
```

index.js

```
const electron = require('electron')
const {app} = electron

const {BrowserWindow} = require('browser-window')

app.on('ready',function(){
var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
   width:800,
   height:600
 })
})
```

node version: 4.4.5

npm version: 2.15.5

Comment: I think you want: const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow.  I don't believe browser-window is a separate module any more.  Check out: https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

Comment: Thanks it worked :)

Comment: Can I create a build of pre-built app of node js using this? If yes then can you please guide me how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@morecchia808 is correct, the way built-in modules are accessed has changed in Electron v1.0. Your code can be fixed as follows:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron
```